# Pass elements of a list in a function

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I have a function that is able to create triples and relationships from text. However, when I create a list of a column that contains text and pass it through the function, it only processes the first row, or item of the list. Therefore, I am wondering how the whole list can be processed within this function. Maybe a for loop would work?

The following line contains the list

```
rez_dictionary = {'Decent Little Reader, Poor Tablet',
 'Ok For What It Is',
 'Too Heavy and Poor weld quality,',
 'difficult mount',
 'just got it installed'}
```

```
from transformers import pipeline

triplet_extractor = pipeline('text2text-generation', model='Babelscape/rebel-large', tokenizer='Babelscape/rebel-large')

# We need to use the tokenizer manually since we need special tokens.
extracted_text = triplet_extractor.tokenizer.batch_decode([triplet_extractor(rez_dictionary, return_tensors=True, return_text=False)[0]["generated_token_ids"]])

print(extracted_text[0])
```

If anyone has a suggestion, I am looking forward for it.

Would it also be possible to get the output adjusted to the following format:

```
# Function to parse the generated text and extract the triplets
def extract_triplets(text):
    triplets = []
    relation, subject, relation, object_ = '', '', '', ''
    text = text.strip()
    current = 'x'
    for token in text.replace("<s>", "").replace("<pad>", "").replace("</s>", "").split():
        if token == "<triplet>":
            current = 't'
            if relation != '':
                triplets.append({'head': subject.strip(), 'type': relation.strip(),'tail': object_.strip()})
                relation = ''
            subject = ''
        elif token == "<subj>":
            current = 's'
            if relation != '':
                triplets.append({'head': subject.strip(), 'type': relation.strip(),'tail': object_.strip()})
            object_ = ''
        elif token == "<obj>":
            current = 'o'
            relation = ''
        else:
            if current == 't':
                subject += ' ' + token
            elif current == 's':
                object_ += ' ' + token
            elif current == 'o':
                relation += ' ' + token
    if subject != '' and relation != '' and object_ != '':
        triplets.append({'head': subject.strip(), 'type': relation.strip(),'tail': object_.strip()})
    return triplets
extracted_triplets = extract_triplets(extracted_text[0])
print(extracted_triplets)
```

Comment: What happens when you `print(extracted_text)` without the `[0]`?

Comment: It remains processing only the first 'triplet' in the list. The full code can be found on the following page, if necessary. https://github.com/Babelscape/rebel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the other entries of `rez_dictionary` inside the batch_decode:

```py
triplet_extractor(rez_dictionary, return_tensors=True, return_text=False)[0]["generated_token_ids"]
```

Use a list comprehension instead:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

rez = ['Decent Little Reader, Poor Tablet',
 'Ok For What It Is',
 'Too Heavy and Poor weld quality,',
 'difficult mount',
 'just got it installed']

triplet_extractor = pipeline('text2text-generation', model='Babelscape/rebel-large', tokenizer='Babelscape/rebel-large')

model_output = triplet_extractor(rez, return_tensors=True, return_text=False)

extracted_text = triplet_extractor.tokenizer.batch_decode([x["generated_token_ids"] for x in model_output])
print("\n".join(extracted_text))
```

Output:

```
<s><triplet> Decent Little Reader <subj> Poor Tablet <obj> different from <triplet> Poor Tablet <subj> Decent Little Reader <obj> different from</s>
<s><triplet> Ok For What It Is <subj> film <obj> instance of</s>
<s><triplet> Too Heavy and Poor <subj> weld quality <obj> subclass of</s>
<s><triplet> difficult mount <subj> mount <obj> subclass of</s>
<s><triplet> 2008 Summer Olympics <subj> 2008 <obj> point in time</s>
```

Regarding the extension of the OP's question, OP wanted to know how to run the function `extract_triplets`. OP can simply do that via a for-loop:

```py
for text in extracted_text:
  print(extract_triplets(text))
```

Output:

```
[{'head': 'Decent Little Reader', 'type': 'different from', 'tail': 'Poor Tablet'}, {'head': 'Poor Tablet', 'type': 'different from', 'tail': 'Decent Little Reader'}]
[{'head': 'Ok For What It Is', 'type': 'instance of', 'tail': 'film'}]
[{'head': 'Too Heavy and Poor', 'type': 'subclass of', 'tail': 'weld quality'}]
[{'head': 'difficult mount', 'type': 'subclass of', 'tail': 'mount'}]
[{'head': '2008 Summer Olympics', 'type': 'point in time', 'tail': '2008'}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer @cronoik. However, I have made some adjustments in my question, as you can see above. Would it also be possible to generate the output to the adjusted format? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have extended my answer to address your extended question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! Would it also be possible to adjust this code to the spacy pipeline version of this piece of code? The reason for this is that spacy is most likely more efficient to process a larger amount of strings. This can be found on the following link: https://github.com/Babelscape/rebel . I will also add it to an extended version of the extended question. In case that it would be better to open up another question, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please open a new questions ;)

Comment: I just created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978882/pass-elements-of-a-list-in-a-function-spacy-pipeline-version . Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just put in the code in this post as well to be sure that it is not missed. : )

Comment: Would there be any possibility to take a look into my other question today? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok, apologies for the inconvenience! : ) However, good to know.